# Selecting specific columns from linked SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a physical server running two instances of SQL Server, one 2008 R2 (port 1433) and one plain 2008 (port 1444).

I have a linked server setup and the following query runs fine from 2008 R2

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LINKEDSERVER,1444].[DBNAME].[dbo].[TABLENAME]
```

When I attempt to run this query I get the error the multi-part identifier could not be bound.

```
SELECT [LINKEDSERVER,1444].[DBNAME].[dbo].[TABLENAME].[COLUMNNAME]
FROM [LINKEDSERVER,1444].[DBNAME].[dbo].[TABLENAME]
```

Can anyone please shed some light on what is going on here? I assume I have a simple syntax error or something but all the examples I can find are just `Select *`, and that's not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried just using the column name in the `SELECT`, rather than fully qualifying it?

Comment: It has to be fully qualified as my queries span across multiple instances of SQL Server and even multiple databases within the same instance.  I know it sounds convoluted, however, it has to be this way for reasons I'm not going to get into here.  The synonym solution worked well for me.  I could have used table aliases, however, I'm querying this constantly and the short name helps immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 levels is the deepest you can go, but if you want to reference a specific column in the case above you can use a table alias.  Putting a space then a letter or shortened abbreviation after the table name in the from space.  The you can reference that alias in the query to alleviate your issue.

```
SELECT abrv.[COLUMNNAME]
FROM [LINKEDSERVER,1444].[DBNAME].[dbo].[TABLENAME] abrv
```

Yet another alternative if you are going to access it via linked server a lot is to actually create Synonym for the table (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) and use it like it is a local table.

Comment: Just a bit of a terminology pet peeve - these should not be called table "abbreviations."  They're table *aliases*.